# Manifestation of negation in proto-indo-european?

Tags: proto-indo-european, negation

Does anybody know when and how linguistic negation was manifested in
proto-language (anyone, for example, proto-indo-european)?

What is meant by "linguistic negation" is these patterns of language
that include negative references, i.e "not this", "not that".

References would be great as well. Thanks.

**Update**

The post by @TKR on [Diachronic sources of negators](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6571/diachronic-sources-of-negators) approaches the spirit of the question, but it is not what is asked here. The question is about initial manifestation (and historical evolution) of negation in language (part of a greater study of *negation*, including linguistics)

Comment: There's no general answer to this question. Proto-languages are just languages like any others, so each one will do things differently.

Comment: @TKR, ok, any research on how negation  was (historicaly) formed in language, it doesnt matter if it is about a specific family of languages, rather than full generality. What i'm interested in, isthe process of negation formation in linguistics, even in a subset of languages

Comment: http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/books/pies04.html scroll down to 4.3.3 Sentence Negation

Comment: Protolanguages are not real languages that exist and can be studied; they're reconstructed formulas that chart the best possible guesses for some parts of a protolanguage's vocabulary, morphology, and phonology, with many many rules for going from the protolanguage to various attested languages. But as far as we know, negation is present in every human language ever encountered. [See here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) for more on the subject.

Comment: Related: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2565/jespersens-cycle-why-is-it-defined-cycle The referenced documents there also may aid answering the question.

Comment: @bytebuster, thanks, will check references, already aware of Jespersen's Cycle, trying to go beyond that (or rather before that)

Comment: @jlawler, correct, but since i'm interested in the historical evolution, it seemed more accurate to form the question this way, about proto-language(s)

Comment: See http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6571/diachronic-sources-of-negators

Comment: @TKR, added a couple more examples in that answer

Comment: You're still not going to get a general answer about the "initial manifestation" of negation (or anything else) in language. No one knows how long ago the first human language(s) was/were spoken, but it was certainly tens of thousands of years before Proto-Indo-European or any other language we know anything about. PIE is no more "initial" than any other language.

Comment: @TKR, ok i gave it a try if anything on that matter was known, thanks